Unable to force brass barb insert for a polyethylene pipe fix
As shown in the screenshot I have the following:

old poly[butylene] (obsolete pipe replaced by polyethylene in 1978)
one inch brass barbed male to male insert.
new polyethylene pipe with clamps already secured on top of the lower male half of the barbed insert


I propane-torched / heated the nearest section of the polybutylene, but I could not force the visible upper male half of the barbed insert into it more than about one thread.  I did have pretty good physical leverage: I was able to kneel and hold at chest level and push hard.  But the barbed insert does demand lots of cajoling: I had had to bang it pretty hard with a light hammer to get the lower half of the insert working.
Any thoughts on how to handle this?  I don't want to heat the poly more than I already have or it might damage the longevity of it.

Did you try to hammer the barb into the old pipe before clamping the new pipe to the other end?  Also, did you cut the old pipe off square?  Hard to tell from the pic.

@Huesmann Emplacing the dual stab/male-male barb in the existing line first was actually recommended by the Water District folks. But I have a 13 foot curving section so there's limited energy I can bring to bear on it. I am waving the white flag and changing to a male/female (hose bib) female/female (hose-hose) then female/male all brass. It's expensive but this section is down 40 inches and I can not get it wrong.  wrt the cutoff: it is just a hair out of square: it would not affect the result if all those barb threads were covered (and two firmly pinched clamps to boot).

Is the existing pipe not buried?

That 40 inches refers to the existing pipe (and thus to the new one as well).  btw your comment about "insert the barb into the partially buried pipe first" is worthy of a (helpful) answer if you'd like to add it.

A hair dryer/hot air gun or very hot/close to boiling water are much better heat sources.
Propane is too hot.
Some lubricant(butter, veg oil, vaseline if not for drinking/don't care) will help also.
Can hit those tighten clamps with a light hammer also, if damaged just replace.

Nice point about the air gun / water: I do believe the propane is too hot as you say.   The Water District folks just reconnected from the water meter and suggested to replace the double-stab with two parts: male/female and female/male . They did say "yea it's hard to get the pipe in".  I'll try your suggestion first in any case.

If heating up the poly pipe with a heat gun or hair dryer doesn't do it then I'd also use dawn dishwash soap since it is a good biodegradable food safe lubricant.
If that still doesn't work I'd consider creating two tongues on one of the pieces of pipe.  Cut two recesses that leave two strip that can be bent back and vice gripped.  Then with the barbed insert into one piece of pipe fully I'd dawn up the inside of the tongued pipe and the outside of the barb and use the two sets of vice grips to pull on the pipe.

This approach may work for internal pipe. This is a high pressure line and I'd not want to chance it.  I'm going to redesigning this connection . Instead of a  single dual -stab (male to male) coupler it will be  three couplers:  male to Hose bib/female (brass), then male to male(brass) then Female (Hose bib) to male . That's a lot more expensive but this stuff is 40 inches down and I do NOT want ANY more problems with it so will get the strongest possible connections.

That's fair.  I don't like barb connectors in general especially with worm drive clamps.  Generally the water service lines that I deal with use cepex connectors.  So in your case I'd probably get something that takes your polyB to MIP or FIP and then use a cepex ( CPS to IP ) connector.  www.lateralconnection.com

When you say high pressure are you talking 80-100psi or something higher?

fair enough I should say fairly high: yea it's 96 psi (measured by the Water District this morning).      By hard knocks that's high enough to knock the socks off anything not buttoned down like real well.
